# Evaluate: $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{x}e^{-x^2}\ln^2(x)\left[\frac{1}{x\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}-\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}\right]dx$

Tags: integration

According to wolfram integrator:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{x}e^{-x^2}\ln^2(x)\left[\frac{1}{x\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}-\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}\right]\mathrm dx=2C+\frac{\pi}{4}\large[\gamma+3\ln(2)]\tag1$$

Does anyone know how to prove $(1)?$

We may try this substitution, $u=\ln\sqrt{x}$, $\mathrm dx=2x\mathrm du=2e^{2u}\mathrm du$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}8u^2e^{u-e^{4u}}\left[\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}\right]\mathrm du-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}8u^2e^{3u-e^{4u}}\left[\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}\right]\mathrm du=I+J$$

Applying IBP to $I$:

$$I=u^2(1-4e^{4u})e^{u-e^{4u}}-2\int u(1-4e^{4u})e^{u-e^{4u}}\mathrm du$$

getting more difficult to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{s-1}e^{-x}dx=\Gamma(s),\,\mathrm{Re}(s)>0$$ we have $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{s-1}e^{-x}\log^{2}(x)dx=\Gamma(s)(\psi(s)^{2}+\psi_{1}(s))$$ where $\psi(x),\,\psi_{1}(x)$ are the Digamma and Trigamma function, respectively. I think you can solve the problem from here.